# Создание файла с русским названием

Tags: кодировка, java

При создании файла в java с русским названием создается файл с названием в кодировке utf 8. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: А Вы хотите, чтобы название было в кодировке cp1251?

Comment: Кодировка оси лежащей под JVM cp1251, но при создании файла все равно имя файла в кодировке utf-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Название файла надо перекодировать в кодировку оси лежащей под JVM. Кодировку оси можно узнать через:

```
String osEncoding=System.getProperty("file.encoding");
```

**Update**
Вообще то кодировка JVM обычно совпадает с кодировкой оси, так что имена файлов должны отражаться правильно. Тут у вас какие-то специфические настройки то ли оси, то ли JVM. В общем какая-то нестандартная ситуация.